# Error Adding New Start View to Existing IOS XCode4 Project

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, storyboard

I have built part of my application following Lynda's Core Data For IOS tutorial.  It begins with a Nav Controller/Table view, and segues into several other views.  All works well.

Problem is, I need to add a basic "Main Menu" home screen.  When I add a new blank view in storyboard, then set it to be the Initial View Controller then b/r, I get a crash.  Doesn't matter if there is a link to another view or not.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x748dce0'
```

If I comment out the code in the appdelegate didfinishloadingwithoptions (see below) the app loads as desired with new blank window.

So I have code in the app delegate didfinishloading that is needed but it crashes the phone on load while it remains in the appdelegate.m

EDIT
Still having other related issue however, I have since added another appdelegate file and now the app loads up to the blank startup window as intended.  However when I then try and navigate to the tableviewcontroller and on it's viewdidload event that fires the fetchresults method and checks the validity of the fetchresultscontroller object, I'm getting this crash error ..

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'PayItemMaster''
*** First throw call stack:

The code that is now causing problems is this

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PayItemMaster"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"payClass"
                                                               ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"payClass" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

....... this code worked fine when that view was being called on app load but causes problems when the view is called from another view (remember the app used to start up to this tableview fine, but I now want it to start up in a "menu view" and later navigate to this tableview that still has al it's original coding)

Comment: You get that error, because somewhere in the code (probably in the app delegate) you're calling the method viewControllers on your initial controller. When that controller was a navigation controller, that worked ok, but now that you put in a plain UIViewController, that no longer works. How to fix this depends on what you're trying to do, which isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, in the appdelagate I am still trying to initialize a navigation controller as you picked up on ... as well as set some context.  If I comment that stuff out the app loads correctly with a new blank screen.  Now, where should I put this code commented out so that the old nav controller will work as it used to? (with that code that used to be in the app delegate)

Comment: How are you trying to initialize a navigation controller? Post your app delegate code.

Comment: this is the original code from the app delegate in the didfinishloadingwithoptions               UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    
    
    PayItemMasterViewController *pimtc = (PayItemMasterViewController *) [[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    pimtc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;             I remove this and get the load i want but need to put this somewhere else

Comment: I can easily the duplicate the process by creating a generic master-detail application as per Xcode 4 build run, all works fine, then can somebody tell me how one could later insert a plain view with buttons into that project, to become the new start view? (to act as a "Main Menu" of sorts)

Comment: It depends on how you want that controller to interact with your other controllers, this question can't be answered in the abstract. You can drag one into the storyboard, and move the arrow to it, but then you need to change any code in the app delegate to what's appropriate for your setup.